Django models "pregunta"
Buen día, en estoy desarrollando un programa con python y django el cual en los modelos agregué dos booleanfield... lo cual en mi forms.py "mi formulario" los puse como CheckboxInput... tengo 2 checkbox pero cuando lleno el formulario puedo elegir los dos checkbox "como opción", quisiera solo poder elegir 1 que restricción puedo agregar para que solo me deje elegir 1... ando un poco lento algún parámetro para esta misma?

En vez de usar CheckBox usa RadioButtons, para ello pon lo siguiente en tu fichero forms.py:
class MiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiModelo
        fields = ['campo1', 'campo2']
        widgets = {
                      'campo1': forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(True, 'Sí'), (False, 'No')]),
                      'campo2': forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(True, 'Sí'), (False, 'No')]),
                  }

En widgets se especifica que tus campos booleanos se representarán en tu formulario como RadioButtons, donde por cada campo habrán dos RadioButtons uno para seleccionar el valor true y otro el false, en este caso por simplicidad cada pareja de RadioButtons se muestra con los textos Si/No, pero perfectamente podría ser Masculino/Femenino o cualquier texto que represente tus necesidades.
